# Adding new controller gives HTTP error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 application, I used to have a controller called `Alpha`, which I played around with for a while, and then ended up deleting it. Now, I've decided that I want to have another controller called `Alpha`, with different functionality from before.

So, I have added a new controller, named it `Alpha`, and added an `Index` view for this controller. But when I go to `localhost:IP/Alpha`, I get the following error:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

All I have done though, is add the controller with the code, and then add an Index view with the default code.

The strange thing, is that if I add a controller and a view in the same way, but call it anything other than `Alpha`, then the application works as would be expected, and `Alpha`'s `Index` view is displayed.

So I am assuming there is something remaining in the system from the old `Alpha` controller (which may have originally been buggy, I cannot remember), which is conflicting with this new `Alpha`. Any ideas on how I might investigate this further?

---

As requested by Jason Evans, here is my Global.asax.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Poseidon
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
        }
    }
}
```

---

As requested by Jason Evans, here is my RoutConfig::RegisterRoutes function:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried to replicate your problem, but failed. Can you show the code of your `global.asax.cs` file, that will contain route mappings for controllers. It may hold a clue as to why you're having problems.

Comment: Sure - see above for the code.

Comment: I'd search your solution for alpha to make it is not showing up anywhere unexpected. I'd also look for a folder named alpha in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Ahh sorry, forgot it's not MVC 3 you're working with (I've been working with that today). Can you show the code in the RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes() method. Apologies for that.

Comment: Have you tried: localhost:IP/Alpha/Index ?

Comment: I have not found any references to Alpha in the solution. I've now added my code for RegisterRoutes().

Comment: Hmmm, odd. Can you access `Home` or `Home/Index`? Do you get same error? I'm not sure what's happened there.

Comment: Oh, actually - localhost:IP/Alpha/Index does in fact work. Only localhost:IP/Alpha is giving me the error message.

Comment: Home and Home/Index, together with all my other controllers, work fine. The only route that is not working is localhost:IP/Alpha.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have an "Alpha" directory in your site root, would you? Probably not, but no one has asked, and that would cause this issue.

Comment: Aha, yes I do! That's the problem then I guess - I just need to change the name - otherwise it is trying to read the contents of my Alpha directory. So a direct address to a path from the site root takes priority over sending anything through a controller?